# How to create new column by manipulating another column? pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to make a new column depending on different criteria.  I want to add characters to the string dependent on the starting characters of the column.
An example of the data:

```
RH~111~header~120~~~~~~~ball
RL~111~detailed~12~~~~~hat
RA~111~account~13~~~~~~~~~car
```

I want to change those starting with RH and RL, but not the ones starting with RA.  So I want to look like:

```
RH~111~header~120~~1~~~~~ball
RL~111~detailed~12~~cancel~~~ball
RA~111~account~12~~~~~~~~~ball
```

I have attempted to use str split, but it doesn't seem to actually be splitting the string up

```
(np.where(~df['1'].str.startswith('RH'),
                  df['1'].str.split('~').str[5],
                  df['1']))
```

This is referencing the correct columns but not splitting it where I thought it would, and cant seem to get further than this.  I feel like I am not really going about this the right way.

Comment: Please show an example of what you want the data sample to look like after it is processed

Comment: You added *1* in row starting with *RH* and *cancel* in row starting with *RL*.
What is the rule **what** to insert?

Comment: the rule is, For all starting with RH you would add 1 after five ~ and RL add cancel after five ~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a function to replace element No *pos* in *arr* list:

```
def repl(arr, pos):
    arr[pos] = '1' if arr[0] == 'RH' else 'cancel'
    return '~'.join(arr)
```

Then perform the substitution:

```
df[0] = df[0].mask(df[0].str.match('^R[HL]'),
    df[0].str.split('~').apply(repl, pos=5))
```

Details:

- `str.match` provides that only proper elements are substituted.
- `df[0].str.split('~')` splits the column of strings into a column
  of lists (resulting from splitting of each string).
- `apply(repl, pos=5)` computes the value to sobstitute.

I assumed that you have a DataFrame with a single column, so its column
name is *0* (an **integer**), instead of *'1'* (a string).
If this is not the case, change the column name in the code above.

Comment: Thank you Valdi, this seems like it would be a relatively common problem but could not find any similar questions before.  maybe I was just searching for the wrong thing.